# how to capture an event for an entire grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid that takes up like a quarter of an interface.  I want to capture an event whenever anyone clicks anywhere withing this grid (or a quarter of the interface).  I created a stackpanel and I'vev set the PreviewMouseDown button, but it's not capturing the event when I click anywhere within the space for the grid.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
         <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                        Name="sp_activationSpace"
                        PreviewMouseDown="testing"></StackPanel>

             ......
```

Comment: Try to move PreviewMouseDown="testing" to the grid instead of stack panel like <Grid PreviewMouseDown="testing" > .

Comment: When I do that, I can click on a button or a label within the grid, and the event is captured.  But it will not capture if I click on white space.  I want it to capture any click I make within the grid.

Comment: Try to check for the type of the OriginalSource in your event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, how the rest of the window looks like, but what I usually do is create a `Rectangle` with usually white background (I don't think it can be transparent but I'm not sure) that is under the `Grid` I want to capture `MouseButtonDown` or `PreviewMouseDown`. It could look like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle PreviewMouseDown="MyGrid_PreviewMouseDown" Margin="0"/>
    <Grid>
        <!--your grid-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                    Name="sp_activationSpace"
                    PreviewMouseDown="testing"></StackPanel>

         ......
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Again, this is a simple and well-functioning solution, however it might not be suitable if you need transparency. I suspect you have just a white (or any solid color) window background.

Comment: A rectangle did not work, but a blank label did.  Close enough.  works like a charm.  Thanks!!!